# Was Installing Syncevolution, when I came across the following messages!

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

I was trying to build syncevoltion, and I came across the following error after `./configure`

```
checking for SQLITE3... configure: error: Package requirements (sqlite3) were not met:

No package 'sqlite3' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables SQLITE3_CFLAGS
and SQLITE3_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

configure: error: configuring Synthesis library failed
```

I have no idea what to do. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./configure` is throwing this error because syncevoltion requires `sqlite3`, which is not installed on your system

So before running configure script, install SQLite 3 developmental package  first using

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

After it execute `./configure`

Comment: I think it's more likely to be the development package `libsqlite3-dev` that's required, no?

Comment: @steeldriver, Thanks for pointing out that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help people. 

I am completely new to this. So what I had done was I did //sudo apt-get install sqlite3 How did you come to know it was //libsqlite3-dev instead?

Comment: It is developmental package for SQlite 3.

Comment: So I should always look at development packages whenever I'm trying ./configure?

Comment: In general, yes. You need to analyse the error to find out the correct package.